# How to do you let the user retry in Python?

Tags: python

I friend of mine asked me to make a simple math test with Python for her class. When the user is wrong the question will repeat infinitely.

```
 test1 = raw_input ("How much is 3+23?")
if (test1 == '26'):
    print "Well done!"
else:
    print "Try again. I'm sure your brain will function correctly this time."
    test1 = raw_input ("How much is 3+23?")
```

I tried doing this but the question is repeated only two times. Is there a way to make infinite retrys without having to type "game1 = raw_input ("How much is 3+23?")" over and over again?

Additionally, some questions might have finite number of retrys. Can I tell Python how many times I want this part of the code to be looped?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop.

Comment: `while` loop, `for` loop.  Maybe google a python tutorial or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an infinite loop, use a [while-loop](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while):

```
# This will run until input = '26'
while True:
    test = raw_input("How much is 3+23?")
    if test == '26':
        # If we got here, input was good; break the loop
        break
    print "Try again. I'm sure your brain will function correctly this time."
print "Well done!"
```

For a limited number of loops, use a [for-loop](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) with [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
# This runs for 10 times max
for _ in xrange(10):
    test = raw_input("How much is 3+23?")
    if test == '26':
        print "Well done!"
        break
    print "Try again. I'm sure your brain will function correctly this time."
```

Comment: You can also break out of the loop, eg. when the user enters `'Do it by yourself!'`, using the `break` keyword.

Comment: I'd recommend using `while True: test = raw_input("How much etc")` and then `break` on a positive result, like you did in the second case, to avoid the duplication of the `raw_input` line.  PS: your current second code won't print `"Well done!"` if you get it right. `else` in a `for` loop means something like "if_we_did_not_break:", but in your case you did break if you got it right.

Comment: The students will have 45 seconds to solve each answer, how do I add a time limit?

Comment: @VagosLabrou - That is a little tricky.  Most likely, it will involve threading (having two pieces of code running side by side in different threads).  Here is a reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html  However, you may want to just open a new question since all this is kinda beyond the scope of this one.